# Definition of luminescence

Tags: solid-state-physics

I saw a definition of luminescence as "any light not resulting from blackbody radiation", but in my view it's too broad. Is an accelerating electron producing luminescence? Or an electron recombining with a positron (or any chemical reaction for that matter)? I think two things are important when defining luminescence:

- The material needs to absorb some sort of energy first. That energy is then converted into the production of new light (a crystal absorbs a 1 keV electron and produces a bunch of visible photons);
- Afterglow.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you please cite the source your statement? I believe the essential point the source is getting at is that the system emitting the so called luminescence cannot be anywhere near thermodynamic equilibrium, since blackbody radiation is radiation with the maximum entropy assignment of its energy to the radiation modes. The definition is a little broad, maybe, for some purposes, but it's a very concise one for thermodynamic purposes.

Comment: The source is actually a private communication with a colleague. But the same thing is written in, e.g., the Wiki article. Still, your explanation raises the same questions as in the original post. Overall, I think the definition is quite good and in practice there is generally no ambiguity. However, strictly speaking, I think it's a little too broad.

Comment: I think that is a good definition within the context of solid state physics. You could also say something like, "emission resulting in radiation with chemical potential", but this is perhaps too narrow a definition! I generally think of luminescence as radiation resulting from electronic recombination where the electronic population is in an excited state (i.e. not in chemical equilibrium).

Comment: Indeed, one generally thinks of luminescence in the context of solid state physics. As reference, a colleague of mine asked whether cold light sources = luminescence sources, which started the whole discussion about the definition of luminescence.